# Regex contain only numbers and does not contain only 0

Tags: java, regex

I would like to implement a regular expression that return true if:

- The string contain only number
- The string does not contain only 0 ( like 0000)

For example:

- 1230456 => true
- 888822200000 => true
- 00000000 => false
- fff   => false

I started to implement this

```
private static final String ARTICLE_VALID_FORMAT = "\\d";
private static final Pattern ARTICLE_VALID_FORMAT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(ARTICLE_VALID_FORMAT);

private boolean isArticleHasValidFormat(String article) {
    return StringUtils.isNotBlank(article) && ARTICLE_VALID_FORMAT_PATTERN.matcher(article).matches();
}
```

Now, it returns true if the article has only number. but i would like to test also if it is not all 0.

How to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
private static final String ARTICLE_VALID_FORMAT = "[0-9]*?[1-9][0-9]*";
```

which means:

- Match zero or more digits; the `?` means to match as few as possible before moving onto the next part
- then one digit that's not a zero
- then zero or more digits

Or, as Joachim Sauer suggested in comments:

```
private static final String ARTICLE_VALID_FORMAT = "0*[1-9][0-9]*";
```

which means:

- Match zero or more zeros
- then one digit that's not a zero
- then zero or more digits

If you wanted to do it without regex, you could use (among many other ways):

```
    string.chars().allMatch(c -> c >= '0' && c <= '9')
 && string.chars().anyMatch(c -> c != '0')
```

Comment: Shouldn't `0*[1-9][0-9]*` work just as well?

Comment: @JoachimSauer yep. You don't need the `?` then too.

Answer (score 2):

The regex pattern `\d*[1-9]\d*` as given by @AndyTurner is a good way to do this.  Another approach would be to try to parse the string input to a long, and then check that it is greater than zero:

```java
private boolean isArticleHasValidFormat(String article) {
    try {
        if (Long.parseLong(article) > 0) return true;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    }

    return false;
}
```

This solution assumes that you are only concerned with finding positive numbers.  If not, and you want to cater to negatives, then check `num != 0` instead.

Comment: (Assuming the value is small enough to be parsed as an int)

Comment: Thanks for this solution , I have used regular expression because I don't want to throw an exception if the string contains charactars that can't be  parsed as number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this condition.

```
(Integer.pasrseInt("0" + article.replaceAll("^[0-9]", "0")) != 0) ? true : false
```

the ["0" +] is to avoid NumberFormatException for empty string

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make a Pattern object. Just call `matches` function from the `String` class

```
article.matches("\\d*[1-9]\\d*");
```

It's the same regex as Andy Turner suggested.

Comment: The reason for creating the `Pattern` object is the regex is compiled once and reused. This code will recompile it each time it's evaluated.

Comment: Ohh, okay. Thanks for sharing your insight.

Comment: Yes that's why I used Pattern.